# Pass parameters from one combo box to another using two forms in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Just started working with Access 2016 for a project I am on.

How can I pass selected data from one form in access to another?

That Selection will be the determining factor on what data is presented in drop down menus. Basically, if I select a department, I want that departments data to be the "select from" data on the next.

I'm not really sure if this is a clear question, so I've added pictures.

The Goal is to not have to create a new form for every department.

[image: Form 1 - Department Selector]

[image: Form 2 - Pic from Data based on department]

> Update:
>
> So I am able to link the department combo box with the lineid box with the following Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Line.lineName, Department.departmentName
 FROM Line INNER JOIN Department ON Line.departmentID = Department.departmentID
 WHERE (((Department.departmentName)=[Forms]![Production_Select_Data_Input_Destination].[OpenArgs]));
```

> [image: Image3]
>   [image]
>
> I need to get the parameter passed so this is not prompt and the combo box for lineId loads a select list of lineId's that are within the selected department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using

```
Private Sub btnEnterDataInput_Click()

 DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDataInput", , , , , , OpenArgs:=cboDepartmentName

End Sub
```

In my first form,
and

```
[Forms]![frmSelectDataInput]![cboDepartmentName]
```

in my second form combobox row source query.

in my second form.